# Loop through array and populate each column in a spreadsheet using Appscript

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm looking for the best way to loop through my array and insert each element into a new column in a google spreadsheet.

At the moment I have  -

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
sheet.appendRow([myArray[i]]);
}
```

but this will put each value into a new row, how do I get it all in one row but in separate columns?

Comment: You need to first use `insertColumns()`, and then use `getRange().setValues()`

Comment: The `appendRow()` method takes a **one** dimensional array.  `setValues()` takes a two dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you try to make things complicated...
This is how it works :

```
  var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5]; // example
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow(myArray);// this will create a row 
  //with each element of the array in a different column
```